# Trying to form group with two users

Tags: group

I am trying to form a group with two users so that only those two users have access to a directory using

```
chmod g+r dir
```

I form a new group, www-OtagoHarbour, and try to add an existing user, OtagoHarbour, like this.

```
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www/executables$ sudo groupadd www-OtagoHarbour
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www/executables$ sudo useradd -G www-OtagoHarbour OtagoHarbour
useradd: user 'OtagoHarbour' already exists
OtagoHarbour@WebServer:/var/www/executables$ sudo useradd -g www-OtagoHarbour OtagoHarbour
useradd: user 'OtagoHarbour' already exists
```

Of course the user 'OtagoHarbour' exists but I want to add it to a group with another user.

Comment: You will also want to give them `x` perms on directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the command `useradd` to add accounts. But once they've been created you use the command `usermod` to modify them.

```
$ usermod -a -G www-OtagoHarbour OtagoHarbour
```

#### References

- [usermod man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod)